# Having trouble making a highscore system

Tags: python, pygame

I'm making my first game, and I'd like to add a highscore system to it. I've already asked this on here, cuz I just didn't know where to start. I've gotten some great help, and thought I had finished this, but after testing it I ran into a problem.
I'll first list the usefull pieces of my code before I explain the problem:

```
score = 0

def update_obstacle_positions(obstacle_list, score): 
     for idx, obstacle_location in enumerate(obstacle_list):
            if obstacle_location[0] >= 0 and obstacle_location[0] < width:
                obstacle_location[0] -= speed
           else:
                obstacle_list.pop(idx) 
                score += 1
        return score

def game_over(): 
    while game_over:
        screen.fill(black)
        text = "Game Over, Press R to restart"
        label = myFont.render(text, 1, white)
        screen.blit(label, (350, 450))
        end_score = "Score:" + str(score)
        label_2 = myFont.render(end_score, 1, white)
        screen.blit(label_2, (350, 250))

    file = open("highscore.txt", "r")
    content = file.read()
    content = str(content)
    if content < str(score):
        file = open("highscore.txt", "w")
            file.write(str(score))
            hs = "You got a new highscore!"
            label_3 = myFont.render(hs, 1, white)
            screen.blit(label_3, (350, 350)) 
            pygame.display.update()
else:
            hs = "Highscore: " + content
            label_3 = myFont.render(hs, 1, white)
            screen.blit(label_3, (350, 350)) 
            pygame.display.update()  
file.close()
```

This is the closest I've got to it fully working, but his has 2 problems (1 rather big one)

First of all, when you beat your highscore, you don't get the"You got a new highscore!"-message, it just says "Score: (your score)" and then "Highscore: (same number as score)"

This doesn't really bother me, but the big problem does.

The big problem is the following: This code remembers the highscore, and updates it every time you beat it, UNTIL you get a score of 10+. So it workes, until you get a score with 2 digits.
This obviously isn't correct. I also have no clue how to fix this. the system is working (almost) flawless, until you get into double digits, which doesn't make any sense to me.

I hope the solution is not to complicated, and that some1 can help me.
I'm still very new to programming. So please keep the exploation as simple as possible

PS: sorry if there is some bad English somewhere, it's not my first language...

Comment: Please narrow the question down to a single specific problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are comparing strings:

```
content = str(content)
if content < str(score):
```

You can do that, but it does not behave the same way, as when you compare numbers.
For example, if you type the following in the console:

```
'13' < '7'
```

It will return True.
When comparing strings the ascii values of the first character is compared. Of course this is not what you usually want.

So if you use int variables when you do logic with the score, it should work. Convert it to str only when you print the score.

Comment: that fixed it indeed, thx! I kinda feel stupid rn, but all that matters is that it works . I still don't get the "You got a new highscore!"-message tho, but as I said, that doesn't really matter for me

Answer (score 1):

About your bigger problem.
You are comparing two strings. "9" > "10" even if 9 < 10.

This might work

```
def game_over(): 
    while game_over:
        screen.fill(black)
        text = "Game Over, Press R to restart"
        label = myFont.render(text, 1, white)
        screen.blit(label, (350, 450))
        end_score = "Score:" + str(score)
        label_2 = myFont.render(end_score, 1, white)
        screen.blit(label_2, (350, 250))

    file = open("highscore.txt", "r")
    content = file.read()
    content = int(content)
    if content < int(score):
        file = open("highscore.txt", "w")
            file.write(str(score))
            hs = "You got a new highscore!"
            label_3 = myFont.render(hs, 1, white)
            screen.blit(label_3, (350, 350)) 
            pygame.display.update()
else:
            hs = "Highscore: " + content
            label_3 = myFont.render(hs, 1, white)
            screen.blit(label_3, (350, 350)) 
            pygame.display.update()  
file.close()
```